# Finding cheapest road with recursion

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I need to find the cheapest road using recursion.
The road starts at point 1 and it needs to go through all the other points(2,3,4,5) and come back to point the 1. The trip cost between each point is in a double dimension array(map).

```
╔═══════════════════════╗
║    1|2|3|4|5|(points) ║
║ 1--0 1 3 4 2          ║
║ 2--1 0 4 2 6          ║
║ 3--3 4 0 7 1          ║
║ 4--4 2 7 0 7          ║
║ 5--2 6 1 7 0          ║
║ (points)              ║
╚═══════════════════════╝
```

This means that for example from point 1 to point 5 there is 2"money" cost, from point 5 to point 4 cost is 7. Every time you switch "direction" in the map. I think attempts should be equal to 25(4! + 1)

```
void FindingRoad(int[][] map, int[] pointsOrder, ref int tripCost, ref int attempts)
{

    if (attempts == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    int tempCost = 0;
    int[] tempPointsOrder = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {

        }
    }
    if (tempCost<tripCost)
    {
        tripCost = tempCost;
        pointsOrder = tempPointsOrder;
    }
    attempts--;
    FindingRoad(map,pointsOrder,ref tripCost,attempts);
}
```

Expected road(points order) output should be 1, 5(2), 3(1), 2(4), 4(2), 1(4) and is cost = 13
Any suggestions on how `for` loop could look like?

Comment: This is the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 main functions. 1st&2nd to create all possible roads and 3rd to calculate their cost. Hope it will be helpful

```
static void AllRoads(int[] a, int size, int n, RoadContainer VisiKeliai, int[][]map)
        {
            // if size becomes 1 then prints the obtained 
            // permutation 
            if (size == 1)
                printArr(a, n, VisiKeliai,map);

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                AllRoads(a, size - 1, n, VisiKeliai,map);

                // if size is odd, swap first and last 
                // element 
                if (size % 2 == 1)
                {
                    int temp = a[0];
                    a[0] = a[size - 1];
                    a[size - 1] = temp;
                }

                // If size is even, swap ith and last 
                // element 
                else
                {
                    int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[size - 1];
                    a[size - 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        static void printArr(int[] a, int n, RoadContainer VisiKeliai, int[][]map)
        {
            string s = "0";
            // Console.WriteLine("dassaddsasdaasdas"  + a.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                // Console.Write(a[i] + " ");
                s += Convert.ToString(a[i]);
            }
            s = s.Insert(s.Length, "0");
            Road r = new Road(s);
            CalculatingPrice(r, map);
            VisiKeliai.AddRoad(r);
            //Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        public static void CalculatingPrice(Road Kelias, int[][] map)
        {           
            //  021430 Road im checking
            Console.WriteLine("Kelias: " + Kelias.Path);
            for (int i = 0; i < Kelias.Path.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                int nextI = i + 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
                    {
                        string a = Convert.ToString(m);
                        string aaa = Convert.ToString(Kelias.Path[i]);
                        string b = Convert.ToString(j);
                        string bbb = Convert.ToString(Kelias.Path[nextI]);
                        if (a == aaa && b == bbb)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(a + "--" + aaa + "---" + b + "----" + bbb + "-------------" + map[j][m]);
                            Kelias.Cost += map[j][m];
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Travelling Saleman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) is an optimization problem which is known to be [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), which means that it is unlikely to admit an efficient optimal algorithm. That being said, it it possible to solve it within an exponential runtime bound using [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Such an algorithm can be found [here](http://akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f08/Artikler/05/Bellman61.pdf), or (in a more recent publication) [here](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2015/5460/pdf/11.pdf).

Comment: I get the idea of TSP but all of these formulas are too hard to understand for me how the function should look like :/